# Display Option BeanProperty on jsp

Tags: scala, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a model which has few optional strings and few mandatory strings.
Eg:

```
case class Sample(
    @BeanProperty text1: String,
    @BeanProperty text2: Option[String] = None)
```

So, while accessing them in my jsp, I need to check if text2 di defined or not and then print it.

Will this work?

```
<c:if test="${sample.text2.defined}">
    ${sample.text2.get}
</c:if>
```

Or is there a better way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${sample.text2.getOrElse("")}` looks better, if you really have to work with jsp.

Comment: This works. But I preferred a different approach. Felt it much cleaner. Instead of using Option in models, I declare them as `@BeanProperty text2 : String = None.orNull` So, in jsp, I could just check if its empty before rendering.

Comment: What is the difference between `null` and `None.orNull`?